# factory bot + PostgreSql not initialising string column named "uuid"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

There is strange issue I am facing. I have a model let say Book it has a **string attribute uuid** with **not null constraint** on PG database. When I try to create Book object using factory bot. It throws not null constraint database exception. But, On the other hand I can create book object easily on rails cli.

## Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :book do
    name { 'Fantacy' }
    description { 'blah-blah' }
    uuid { SecureRandom.uuid }
    association :author
  end
end
```

Exception:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "uuid" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, fantacy, blah-blah, null).
```

Factory bot version: 5.1.1

Update:  The problem was another association "author" which was missing initialization of UUID attributes. and ActiveRecord exception wasn't showing name of table. so, I confused it main object "book".

Comment: what is the content of your UuidGenerator.call method?

Comment: From the post it appears to be null, see the `row contains (7, fantacy, blah-blah, null)`

Comment: Is `UuidGenerator` from a gem? Could you try `uuid { SecureRandom.uuid }`?

Comment: replaced UuidGenerator with uuid { SecureRandom.uuid } but still same problem. as UuiGenerator was just a wrapper on SecureRandom.uuid.

Comment: What's being generated by running `FactoryBot.build :book` in `rails console`? does it pre-set `uuid` to the initialized instance? Also, check your validations in the `Book` model. Probably something protects it from writing.

Also - are you sure `uuid` column has a `string` data type in PSQL, not `uuid`? This potentially can happen if you try to assign an attribute of an imcompatible type, i.e. `random string` to a `integer` field, or in this case, `uuid` field.

Comment: Yes, it initializes UUID on the build but when I try to save it PG::NotNullViolation: occures.

Comment: an column type is string as mentioned in the question.